# How to link a running docker container with mysql?

Tags: mysql, docker, jenkins, containers

I want to connect my already running jenkins container with mysql database which is another container. Have created a database named jenkins and user named jenkins in mysql.

Can it be done without using the run command coz run installs a fresh image and i want to use the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `docker network connect` to connect both containers to the same network, so they can communicate. See [docker network connect](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_connect/)